# Debugging Jinja2 templates in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jinja2

So I found the `"jinja: "true"` option for launch.json and am trying to make jinja debugging work, unsuccessfully so far.

My launch.json is currently:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": " uvicorn debug",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch", // set to "test" for "justMyCode" to work. 
            "module": "uvicorn",
            "args":
            [
                "project.asgi:app",
                "--reload",
            ],
            "jinja": true,
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ] }
```

I faced a problem that I could not set up breakpoints in jinja template file, but solved it adding `"debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere": true` to vscode settings.

My questions are as follows:
a) How is debugging template supposed to work? I add  breakpoint anywhere in the template and execution stops there? Or maybe this `'jinja': true` means something completely different?
b) Based on the response on a), if breakpoints in jinja template file should work, how to make this happen, as currently they seem to just be ignored?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I search the source code and found a jinja debug file in the ms-python extension extensions/ms-python.python-2020.5.86806/pythonFiles/lib/python/old_ptvsd/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd_plugins/jinja2_debug.py it talks about jinja-breakpoints and jinja-lines but I have no clue how to set these

Comment: for `debugpy` (used when I launch a python program) there is a similar plugin

Comment: I added an issue for `debugpy`: https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/381

Comment: the initial comment on the issue was "Just set the option and it works". Not for me. So I asked for additional explanation.

Answer (score 5):

First I tried the example on the [Jinja Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinja_(template_engine))

`**jinja-test.py**`

```
from jinja2 import Template
with open('example.html.jinja') as f:
    tmpl = Template(f.read())
print tmpl.render(
    variable = 'Value with <unsafe> data',
    item_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
)
```

`**example.html.jinja**`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ variable|escape }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  {%- for item in item_list %}
    {{ item }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
  {%- endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**Make sure the Language type of the template file is set to `Jinja`.** Otherwise you can't set breakpoints.

Because the file was read to a string before given to the Jinja Template class there was no link to the breakpoint set on the template.

Reading the source code of `jinja2.Template` I found that the preferred way of creating a `jinja2.Template` is through the `jinja2.Environment` instance.

After a search I found an other [Jinja usage example on SO using the `jinja2.Environment` a Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002357/how-to-debug-jinja2-template).

`**jinja-test-2.py**` using a FileSystemLoader

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))
# env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
tmpl = env.get_template('example.html.jinja')

print (tmpl.render(
    variable = 'Value with <unsafe> data',
    item_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
```

`**jinja-test-2.py**` using a PackageLoader

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader
env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('main', 'templates'))
tmpl = env.get_template('example.html.jinja')

print (tmpl.render(
    variable = 'Value with <unsafe> data',
    item_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
```

Because Jinja uses the module `pkg_resources` you must add an empty `main/__init__.py` if you use the PackageLoader. Or you get an Exception

```
"Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type"
```

When you now set a breakpoint in the template and run the application the debugger stops in the template and you can step through with F10.

**Make sure the Language type of the template file is set to `Jinja`.** Otherwise you can't set breakpoints.

Comment: In my case the key here was the switch from loading the template as a string and switching to loading it as part of the Environment - which in hindsight makes complete sense.  Also for anyone wondering these are the instructions for changing the language for a file in VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file